# How to transfer some data between two SQL Servers that are not connceted

Tags: sql-server

I am a new SQL developer (not DBA or Architect) and I'm working on a new system for the directors of a company.

This company has around 50 dependencies and each one of them use the same desktop system for their inventory. The database of this system is not centralized, in every branch office they have their own individual database and it's not shared.

Now the directors of the company want to supervise all the inventory of the company, so they want that at the end of every day the data of each branch is transferred to a centralized database at the company server.

These are all SQL Server 2008 R2 databases. I am tasked with figuring out how to:

- Transfer that data (is not a complete replication of those databases because they only want some of it) to the centralized database without direct data access between the databases of each brach and the database at the company server (they don't want it)

I have read a number of articles on the internet but almost every one of them talk about transactional replication and the use of SSIS (this was my first option when they assigned me this task) to transfer the data between the SQL servers, but I can't do that, they don't want a direct connection between the databases of the brach and the company due to technical limitations imposed by the network administrators (also I can only use ports 80 and 443).

I am hoping some of you with more experience with SQL and integration can help me with that.

I have been thinking about using web services, but I have no idea I have no idea where to start. Sorry if this may be a trivial question but I have been working as an android developer and all this is new to me.

Comment: That sounds like a really terrible situation you have to work with. Funny how they want all the data connected but actively make it damn difficult to do that by preventing the servers to speak to each other. Even a linked server would make this a lot easier. Is SSIS an option?

Comment: SSIS packages may be the right option. You filter your intial selection the way you like, transform if necessary, and point to the destination. We have a slightly similar situation where we move data to our data warehouse. We have a sql job scheduled to do the movement every night.

Comment: Do they really need all data every evening or only some aggregated ones?

Comment: Strongly consider not taking on this task if you're inexperienced, at least not as advertised. Being restricted to HTTP/HTTPS basically means writing things from scratch. They're asking you to do something that I would find annoying and difficult to get working correctly, securely and with performance -- and I have almost 20 years of experience with both .NET and SQL Server. It's not a small thing to do, and you can bet they'll look to you if the data somehow ends up in the wrong hands.

Comment: What Jeroen said. Without experience your path most likely leads to failure. At the very least, now is the time to consult with the DBA. And your organization needs to have a very good and frank discussion about the continued use of an obsolete version of sql server.

Comment: the problem is that the sql servers ar ein different LAN nteworks, and the dependencies network admins are the real problem here, because they are the ones that impose the those limitations.

Comment: See if your network admins have heard of the marvelous innovation known as the VPN tunnel, which allows tunneling between trusted networks over an untrusted medium. It's work for them, but if you tell management they can make the VPN more secure than you can securely make a public transmission over an HTTPS channel, they might come around -- and with some luck you can even get direct connections to port 1433 this way. You really don't want the responsibility of having to deal with certificates and encryption, as that's not even part of the core problem.